# Firebase: get getReferenceFromUrl()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

```
imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dd);
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://MyProject.appspot.com/");
storageRef.child("MyFolder/MyPict.jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(uri).into(imageView);
                }
            })
          .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                }
            });
```

But.. "Unfortunately YourApp has stoped" is displayed..
Can you help me please

Comment: logcat error ? , picture of your database ?

Comment: You need to start by learning [how to debug](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/) and [how to read logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat).

Comment: What is the error from the logcat?

Comment: i want to dispalay a picture from storage into a ImageView

Comment: whene i use load by link it works well but i want to use  the picture name not the link

Answer (score 1):

I hope you give rules in firebase storage as reading and write true.

on button click used below method ..

```
private void uploadImage() {
    // Start by getting our StorageReference
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference rootRef = storage.getReference();
    StorageReference bearRef = rootRef.child("images/bear.jpg");
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
    progressDialog.show();

    // Get the data from the image as bytes
    ImageView bearImage = getSelectedBearImage();
    bearImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bearImage.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = bearImage.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    // Upload it to our reference
    UploadTask uploadTask = bearRef.putBytes(data);
    buttonDownload.setEnabled(false);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Upload failed: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Download Url: " + downloadUrl);
            buttonDownload.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
}
```

and I hope you add internet permission on android manifest file...

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

for information you can refer this link..
More Information For Storage :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

For Upload & Download :

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-tutorial-android/

Comment: whene i use         
url="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MyProj.appspot.com/o/IMG_84316904172291.jpeg?alt=media&token=bsdds7ee4df4-0328-43dd63-8af37-4fa297d9dd24b5
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(imagevew);
it works well but i want to use the picture name instead the link.. How can i do it.?

Comment: The same for          FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://MyProj.appspot.com/natio/agr-svt-2009-6-cr.jpg");
        Glide.with(this )
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(gsReference)
                .into(t);

Answer (score 1):

use `storage.getStorage().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://MyProject.appspot.com/");`